# iText rectangle - can't remove border

Tags: itext

I can't seem to remove the border on a rectangle! See code below, I am creating a link using a PDFannotation. The links all work but each rectangle has a border.

```
PdfAnnotation annotation;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + tab.getScaledWidth(),      yOffset+tab.getScaledHeight());

rect.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

annotation = PdfAnnotation.createLink(writer, rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE,      PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(section.GetStartPageIndex() + 1,destination, writer));

stamper.addAnnotation(annotation,i);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've realised it's the annotation which has the border, to remove use

```
annotation.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0f, 0f, 0f));
```

Comment: I upvoted your question, and I would recommend you to approve your own answer. That way, other people can see that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
annotation.BorderStyle = new PdfBorderDictionary(0f, 0);
```